# Does a binary relation on the set A have to contain all elements in A?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Say I have the set $$A = \{1,2,3,4\}$$ 
and the relation $$R = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$$
Is this a valid relation?

Also, is the relation anti-symmetric, symmetric and also not reflexive?

Answer (score 1):

A binary relation on $A$ is just a set of ordered pairs in $A^2$. $\emptyset$ is a relation on $A$, albeit an uninteresting one, so by no means does every element of $A$ have to be "in" the relation (what you're really asking is if each element of $A$ is in an ordered pair in the relation).

Your statements about the relation are all correct, though you should try to prove them if you want to be certain.